# Optimize SQL Server 2008 query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

Update: edited the table alias.

I am trying to find whether the below query can be rewritten to improve performance. We started noticing huge performance impact on the query recently. Person table has close to 10 million and Contact table has close to 17 million 
records.

```
SELECT 
    ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT,
    CASE 
       WHEN PrimaryContact = 'MOBILE'
          THEN (SELECT TOP 1 MOBILE 
                FROM CONTACT 
                WHERE ContactType = 'MOBILE' AND CONTACT.PID = PERSON.PID)
          ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 HOME 
                FROM CONTACT 
                WHERE CONTACTTYPE = 'HOME' AND CONTACT.PID = PERSON.PID),
FROM 
    PERSON
WHERE 
    DEPARTMENT = @DEPARTMENT
```

Each person can have one/multiple Mobile/Home phone number in contact table. Based on primary contact type, it should fetch only one phone number based on the `PrimaryContact` type.

On a side note, we are also planning to partition the `Person` table based on `Department`.

Any suggestions to improve the overall performance will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your query is so far from being syntactically correct that it doesn't make sense.  What is `DETAILS`?

Comment: Sorry, that is PERSON.PID instead of DETAILS.PID

Comment: Have you looked at the **execution plans** for this query? What do they show?? Also: what are your table structures, and what indexes are in place already?

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.NAME, p.DEPARTMENT,
       (CASE WHEN p.PrimaryContact = 'MOBILE'
             THEN (SELECT TOP 1 c.MOBILE
                   FROM CONTACT c 
                   WHERE c.ContactType = 'MOBILE' AND c.PID = p.PID
                  )
             ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 c.HOME
                   FROM CONTACT c
                   WHERE c.CONTACTTYPE = 'HOME' AND c.PID = p.PID
        END)
FROM PERSON p
WHERE p.DEPARTMENT = @DEPARTMENT;
```

You should start with indexes:  `person(department, primarycontact, pid)` and `contact(pid, contacttype, home, mobile)`.

Normally, when you use `TOP`, you would have an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks, I will add index and check the performance. Is there any other scope of rewriting the query ?

Answer (score 0):

First why you need 10 million record at one time ?( paging ?)

you can rewrite your query like this,fix the bug ,clear cache then run.

```
SELECT 
    ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT,

           (SELECT TOP 1 CASE when ContactType='MOBILE' then MOBILE else Home end
                FROM dbo.CONTACT  with (nolock)
                WHERE  CONTACT.PID = PERSON.PID
                and ( (PrimaryContact = 'MOBILE' and ContactType = 'MOBILE') or (PrimaryContact != 'MOBILE' and ContactType = 'Home')) )

FROM 
    dbo.PERSON P with (nolock)
WHERE 
    DEPARTMENT = @DEPARTMENT
```

Even you can use inner join with similar condition and check yourself.

my index suggesation,

```
clustered index on person.PID
clustered index on contact.PID
non clustered index on person.DEPARTMENT include(name,PrimaryContact)
non clustered index on contact.ContactType include(MOBILE,Home)
```